# Find least frequent value in whole dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

my dataframe is something like this

```
>   93  40  73  41  115 74  59  98  76  109 43  44
    105 119 56  62  69  51  50  104 91  78  77  75
    119 61  106 105 102 75  43  51  60  114 91  83
```

It has 8000 rows and 12 columns

I wanted to find the least frequent value in this whole dataframe (not only in columns).

I tried converting this dataframe into numpy array and use `for` loop to count the numbers and then return the least count number but it it not very optimal. I searched if there are any other methods but could not find it.

I only found [scipy.stats.mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) which returns the most frequent number.

is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What would happen if there are multiple values with same frequencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `stack` and take the `value_counts`:

```
df.stack().value_counts().index[-1]
# 69
```

`value_counts` orders by frequency, so you can just take the last, though in this example many appear just once. `69` happens to be the last.

Comment: thanks! this helped me a lot. I did not know about `stack`. I will look more into it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `pandas.DataFrame.apply` with `pandas.Series.value_counts`:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).sum(1).idxmin()
# 40
# There are many values with same frequencies.
```

To my surprise, `apply` method seems to be the fastest among the methods I've tried (reason why I'm posting):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 1000, (500000, 100)))

%timeit df2.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).sum(1).idxmin()
# 2.36 s ± 193 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df2.stack().value_counts().index[-1]
# 3.02 s ± 86.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
uniq, cnt = np.unique(df2, return_counts=True)
uniq[np.argmin(cnt)]
# 2.77 s ± 111 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As opposed to my understanding of `apply` being very slow, it even outperformed `numpy.unique` (perhaps my coding is wrong tho ;().

Comment: You're applying column-wise, and there are 100 columns. To better compare how they scale, try `df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 1000, (500, 10000)))`